# Multiple linear regression back-transformations

Tags: multiple-regression, lognormal-distribution, back-transformation

My Multiple Linear Regression equation is (I had log-transformed swim beach *E. coli* and canal *E. coli* for the MLR since the data were not normal):

(LN)Swim Beach *E. coli* = 2.4 + 0.43 * Reservoir Level Change (in/day) + 0.29 *(LN) Canal *E. coli*

I'm now trying to use that equation to predict swim beach *E. coli* concentration depending on daily reservoir level change and canal *E. coli*  levels. To do this am using the following equation in Excel:

=EXP(2.4 + (0.43 * Reservoir Level Change (in/day)) + EXP(0.29 *(LN) Canal E. coli))

The results make sense numerically, but I want to make sure that I am using the EXP function and parentheses in the correct locations. The first EXP should take the result out of log format; the second EXP is meant to be associated with the canal *E. coli*, but it is also associated with the 0.29 coefficient. Is that correct? If I move the EXP to just before the canal *E. coli* and not include the 0.29, then the result doesn't make numerical sense.

Here is the raw data:

```
Reservoir Level Change (in/day) (LN) Swim Beach E coli (#/100ml)    (LN) Canal E coli (#/100ml)
2.4 3.80666249  0
1.56    1.987874348 0
0.72    3.658420247 0
0.12    3.514526067 0
0   3.058707073 0
0.12    4.705920089 0
0   2.595254707 0
-0.36   5.159055299 3.90197267
-0.84   2.674148649 3.90197267
-0.12   3.723280881 3.90197267
-0.12   3.953164949 3.90197267
-1.32   3.242592351 3.90197267
0.12    3.072693315 3.765840495
-2.28   3.605497845 3.765840495
-2.28   3.169685581 3.765840495
-2.28   2.501435952 3.765840495
0.36    3.981549068 3.214867803
0.12    6.361993085 3.214867803
0.12    2.388762789 3.214867803
0   7.791357516 3.214867803
0   5.670225691 3.214867803
0.12    2.850706502 3.214867803
0.12    1.098612289 3.214867803
-0.12   1.410986974 4.650143552
0   2.014903021 4.650143552
0.36    4.564348191 4.650143552
0.24    3.887730313 4.650143552
-1.92   4.280824129 4.650143552
-2.04   2.451005098 3.000719815
-3.72   2.839078464 3.000719815
-0.84   2.128231706 3.000719815
-0.84   1.131402111 0
0.72    2.388762789 4.579339426
1.44    5.561834812 3.751854253
0.48    4.796616651 3.751854253
0.36    3.839452313 3.751854253
0.48    2.57261223  3.751854253
1.08    3.39785848  3.751854253
2.88    4.509760001 3.751854253
4.8 7.254107123 3.751854253
2.76    6.475124503 3.751854253
2.76    7.348008213 2.332143895
3.36    5.249127122 2.332143895
3.36    4.90823336  2.332143895
3.36    4.509760001 2.332143895
2.4 3.802208139 2.332143895
-1.8    2.140066163 2.332143895
-0.96   2.397895273 2.332143895
-1.08   1.987874348 2.332143895
-1.2    4.864452784 1.945910149
-0.6    2.388762789 1.945910149
-0.96   2.397895273 1.945910149
-0.6    1.098612289 1.945910149
-1.44   2.76000994  1.945910149
-0.12   2.681021529 1.945910149
-0.48   1.808288771 5.265794175
0.96    1.648658626 1.931521412
1.08    0.693147181 1.931521412
1.08    1.410986974 1.931521412
1.32    3.871201011 2.772588722
1.8 3.580737295 2.772588722
1.44    2.501435952 2.772588722
1.56    2.397895273 2.772588722
1.56    3.328626689 2.772588722
1.68    4.361823927 2.772588722
-0.36   3.277144733 6.075805696
0.12    5.282187985 6.075805696
-0.6    7.791357516 6.075805696
-0.84   3.303216973 6.075805696
-0.96   3.254242969 6.075805696
-0.84   3.594568775 6.075805696
-0.6    3.139832618 6.075805696
0.48    2.151762203 2.694627181
0.6 2.501435952 2.694627181
-0.48   2.014903021 2.694627181
-0.96   2.57261223  2.694627181
-0.48   2.772588722 2.694627181
```

Comment: There is just ONE exponentiation needed, around the entire right-hand side. EXP( 2.4 + 0.43 * Reservoir Level Change (in/day) + 0.29 *(LN) Canal _E. coli_)). The fact that you logged one predictor has no consequences for back-transformation, as you are back-transforming the prediction, and how you got that is immaterial. I have to underline that MS Excel is a poor environment for even this kind of analysis. Good software would always offer a direct  prediction routine, function or command. (What you may be missing in Excel I can't advise on.)

Comment: Very helpful. So in that last part of the equation (0.29 *(LN) Canal E. coli)), should I be plugging in a log-transformed E. coli value or a non-transformed E. coli value? The input the MLR (via XLSTAT software) was log transformed.

Comment: In this example, the 2.33 is the log of 10.3 and represents canal E. coli. =EXP(2.47+((0.44*2.5)+(0.29*2.33))). The result of that equation is: 69.80. If I use the 10.3 value instead of 2.33, then the result of that equation is 704.15. The part that I'm confused by is that the 69.8 seems too low and the 704 is much to high to seem 'real.' But when I had that extra EXP in the equation, the result was 251, which seems spot on.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you mention 10.3 for canal *E. coli* and 2.5 for reservoir level change.

In Stata's Mata, which I use here because I like it and because the syntax is very similar to that in many programs, I get

```
: 2.47 + 0.44 * 2.5  + 0.29 * ln(10.3)
  4.24632173

: exp(2.47 + 0.44 * 2.5  + 0.29 * ln(10.3))
  69.84801936
```

So I confirm 69.8 (but not 69.80). This should be the evaluation of a single expression in any modern language, not a series of steps. Naturally there should be no rounding of intermediate results.

I also note with small alarm that the intercept is 2.4 in one place and 2.47 in another and one coefficient is 0.43 in one place and 0.44 in another.

The bigger deal is threefold:

1. Inserting the extra `EXP()` is incorrect mathematics, as previously explained. The fact that you logged one predictor has no consequences for back-transformation, as you are back-transforming the prediction, and how you got that is immaterial to the back-transformation. It's on a level with `exp(2)` being whatever it is; how 2 was calculated in the first place doesn't affect the answer.
2. The report that the predicted value is "too low" is not a report that we can comment on without seeing what is being predicted. I would recommend a plot of observed versus predicted beach values on (a) original scales (b) logarithmic scales.
3. We can't check the original regression either.

It's a side-issue but transforming because the original data were not normal is likely to be a case of doing the right thing for the wrong reason. Contrary to a widespread myth, there is no assumption that any marginal distribution in regression is normal. My guess is that logging concentrations is likely to be a good idea to make the relationship more nearly linear, but there you go.

At a wild guess from acquaintance with environmental data I'd guess that this dataset isn't large, so posting the dataset should be feasible and would make your question much clearer and allow independent checks of everything. If your data are confidential or sensitive, give us an example with fake data of similar kind.

EDIT

With the data as posted (and they will be rounded a bit) I confirm in Stata the regression in essentials:

```
. regress beach change canal

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        77
-------------+----------------------------------   F(2, 74)        =     10.15
       Model |  40.0166718         2  20.0083359   Prob > F        =    0.0001
    Residual |  145.878229        74  1.97132741   R-squared       =    0.2153
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.1941
       Total |    185.8949        76  2.44598553   Root MSE        =     1.404

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       beach |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      change |   .4374817   .1090702     4.01   0.000     .2201545    .6548089
       canal |   .2901326   .1051722     2.76   0.007     .0805724    .4996928
       _cons |   2.465561    .366699     6.72   0.000     1.734897    3.196224
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And trying out the example prediction I get

```
. di _b[_cons] + _b[canal] * 2.33 + _b[change] * 2.5
4.2352737

. di exp(_b[_cons] + _b[canal] * 2.33 + _b[change] * 2.5)
69.080586
```

where whatever is unfamiliar to people not using Stata (`_b` and so forth) refers to coefficient estimates as held with maximal precision. `di` just means `display`.

An observed versus predicted plot underlines that the response (beach values) varies from about 2 to about 2400; there is nothing out of order in a back-transformed prediction of about 69 (in the units given).

[image]

EDIT 2

Some small questions arise from looking at some graphs. First quantile plots of the distributions. The vertical axis labelling may look odd until it is realised that the labels are for minimum, maximum, median and quartiles.

[image]

Second, a scatter plot matrix:

[image]

Questions:

a. The canal data appears to be just for several distinct sites and/or times. Correct?

b. The small spike for canal = 0 (log scale) or 1 (raw scale) looks like a small fudge. Correct?

Comment: Please excuse my rounding- the full equation is here: (LN) Swim Beach E coli (#/100ml) = 2.4655605776333+0.437481678806567*Reservoir Level Change (in/day)+0.290132603050201*(LN)Canal E coli (#/100ml). I can't seem to get this to show in table format which is why I hadn't posted data, but here is an attempt: Column 1 = Reservoir Level Change (in/day), Column 2 = (LN) Canal E. coli (#/100 mL), Column 3 =Canal E. coli (#/100 mL)
1.0  0.00  1
1.5  1.16  3
2.0  2.33  10
2.5  3.00  20
3.0  3.77  43
3.5  4.90  134
4.0 ; 6.08 ; 435

Comment: Thank you! So if I am understanding correctly, the EXP at the beginning of the equation is the way to go. exp(2.47 + 0.44 * 2.5  + 0.29 * ln(10.3))
  69.84801936
Correct? Thanks again for staying up late to help on this.

Comment: Correct: that is the main point. All else looks fine. The data don't show a strong relationship, but such data are messy.